# Why was Leela required to have brown eyes?

Tags: doctor-who

The character of Leela was introduced in the fourth Doctor story *[The Face of Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Face_of_Evil)*. Louise Jameson apparently wore red contact lenses to turn her blue eyes brown that caused her great discomfort and she was unable to wear them for long periods.

By the time of the *[Horror of Fang Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_of_Fang_Rock)*, Jameson apparently made the removal of the contacts a condition for her to agree to play the part for another season. This was achieved by having her looking directly into a bright explosion causing a pigment dispersal.

But what was the reason for requiring Leela to have brown eyes? There seems to be no obvious plot point for this to be necessary.

Comment: I was awfully confused for a minute by your second paragraph. I thought you were saying that the production crew had *Jameson* look into a bright explosion in order to turn her eyes brown!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Because it fit the name.

Louise Jameson herself, the actress who played Leela, did an interview with *Doctor Who Magazine* in which she answered this question. The interview is reproduced [on the interviewer's blog](http://0tralala.blogspot.com/2015/12/was-leela-black.html) (emphasis mine):

> To begin with, Louise wore contact lenses to make her blue eyes look brown. In pictures from an early make-up test, her skin looks very dark. Was Leela intended to be the show's first black companion? It was still fairly common for white actors to "black up" – in Leela's third story, The Talons of Weng-Chiang, the white actor John Bennett was made up to look Chinese.
>
> Louise is candid. "It was never specified with Leela. Quite honestly, in those photos I think the make-up woman just didn't get it quite right. **The dark eyes were because, I was told, Leela meant 'dark-eyed beauty'."** Again, she considers. "There was always an hour and a half in make-up before I was allowed on set. I wasn't black but it was more than a tan. One of my sons is mixed race – dual heritage we say now. I think I was meant to have that kind of skin."

I checked a few sources and couldn't find any reference for Leela (or related names like Leila) meaning specifically someone with dark *eyes*, but the name is definitely related to darkness: [The Bump](https://www.thebump.com/b/leela-baby-name) says it means "night beauty", [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leila_(name)) says it refers to darkness or night, and [Baby Name Wizard](https://www.babynamewizard.com/baby-name/girl/leila) says it comes from the Persian for "dark-haired". Anyway, the connection with darkness in general is enough to justify the decision to make Leela a dark-eyed character.

Interestingly, the actress didn't know (at the time she was playing Leela) the *specific* origins of her character's name, after the Palestinian [Leila Khaled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leila_Khaled):

> Indeed, she was named after a terrorist who'd been in the news – Leila Khaled of the Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine.
>
> "Oh really?" laughs Louise.
>
> She didn't know?
>
> "Certainly not back then. I based Leela on a three-year-old who lived upstairs from me and on Bosie, my then dog."

Comment: I believe the word "***Laila***" means night beauty, not Leela. But they're close enough that someone could easily make the error in a pre-Internet era

Comment: In some South Asian languages, including Hindi, the name Leela is common, and is unrelated to Leila (which is also common). Leela can mean a kind of play or skit, often but not necessarily of a religious nature.

Comment: Funny, nowadays when I hear the name "Leela", the only thing I think about her eyes is that she's only got one of them...